# Elasticsearch As ETL & Reporting

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, reporting, etl

I have CSV File's With Different Columns With Few Common Columns, We Are Currently Using Excel To Remove Unwanted Rows Clean The Data, and Generate Reports, I Am Thinking Of Using Elasticsearch As A Solution For Data Storage, Transformation, Load And Reporting.

Is Elasticsearch A Good Choice For This Use Case ?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Search is, as the name indicated, using to quick search. It is build upon Lucene and similar to another Apache project, Solr...

If you want to query the raw data or do some simple aggregation upon it. It is fine and you can also use Kibana to come up with some fancy GUI so your audience can interact with the data and you can even come up with some dashboard to demonstrate some basic staff. However, it is not a replacement of a data base.

If you want to update or join..  you had better use some data base ... sql + mongo or hive for big data.